# Avalonia - populate list box and read selected file

Tags: c#, wpf, avalonia

I want to create listbox and populate it with values from list. Then read selected value.
Trivial thing in WPF, in Avalonia it is a challenge I'm unable to solve it. My current (not working) code:

```xml
<ListBox
            Grid.Row="1"
            Items="{Binding ListOfItems.Name}"
            SelectionMode="Single"
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"
            SelectionChanged="OnSelectionChanged">
</ListBox>
```

```cs
public class Item
    {
        public string Name { get; set; } = String.Empty;
        public Enum Type { get; set; }
    }
```

```cs
public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private Item selectedItem;
        private ObservableCollection<Item> items;
        public ObservableCollection<Item> Items
        {
            get => items;
            set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref items, value);
        }
        public Item SelectedItem
        {
            get => selectedItem;
            set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref selectedItem, value);
        }

        public void Initialize()
        {
            Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
            var temp = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Type)).Cast<Type>().ToList();
            foreach(var item in temp)
            {
                var newObject = new Item
                {
                    Name = Methods.GetDescription(item),
                    Type = item
                };
                Items.Add(newObject);
            }
        }
    }
```

Nothing appears on the list. Similar code in WPF would work with no issues, so I'm out of ideas.

Comment: what is `Items="{Binding ListOfItems.Name}"`?? shouldn't it be `ItemsSource="{Binding Items}`?